# Install ubuntu and windows 10 in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.10

i want to install ubuntu 20.10 (1º option) and windows 10 (2º option) in my machine.
I have UEFI and i read somewhere thath i dont need more to create swap etc partitions, that linux made that alone. Anyone can give me a sugestion or some link with a good tutorial.
Thanks. Best Regards!

Comment: I presume Windows 10 is already installed? In that case I would not recommended erasing it, rather shrinking it in size and installing Ubuntu along side it.

Comment: Think about installing 20.04 instead, it has 4 more year of support, 20.10 is out of support 9months after last October, so around this coming June.  21.04 will be out in April, can try it now as beta version(also 9 months of support).

Comment: UEFI installs to gpt partitioned drives also need an ESP - efi system partition. Swap partition now optional. Some still suggest it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single disk mounted on your device, you should consider manually partitioning it while installing Ubuntu. Because the disk will be locked and you won't be able to shrink or resize the partition to create free space if you let Ubuntu to do this automatically. You can still shrink but it will require booting ubuntu via an usb drive.

While installing Ubuntu, choose something else and manually create `EFI` , `swap`, `/` and `/home` partitions. EFI = 1024 MB, swap area = size of your RAM, / = minimum 8 GB and /home = according to your needs. Use the remaining unallocated space to install windows.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install Ubuntu and windows 10 in the dual boot;

1. Create a backup [optional]
2. Make a live USB/disk of Ubuntu
3. Create a partition where Ubuntu will be installed
4. Disable fast startup in Windows [optional]
5. Disable secure boot in Windows 10
6. Installing Ubuntu along with Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iSAyiicyQY**

This will help...also if rufus is giving problem, it did have problems when I was trying to install it on laptop dell Inspiron 5559 I don't know why it was doing it just gave a black screen, then after a time I tried with another software **BalenaEtcher** then it worked.

Go to CMD as an administrator and type this command.

**bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi**

it will enable the bootloader so you can choose which OS you want to use... It worked for me too.